# How to convert mongo.InsertOneResult's InsertedID to []byte

Tags: mongodb, go

Hi all I am struggling to convert the InsertedID of an InsertOne() Operation to a byte slice*. I am using this mongoDB client library https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver

---

So far I have tried to use TypeAssertion directly like this:

```
res.InsertedID.([]byte)
```

which compiles, but results in the following error during the assertion:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is primitive.ObjectID, not []uint8

I have also tried to use multiple TypeAssertions or the `[]byte()` function directly, but could not get it to compile

---

*byte slice is in this case desired because I am using gRPC, which limits the possible types I can use for return values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InsertedID` is a `primitive.ObjectID`, which is `[12]byte`. So you can do this to get a byte slice:

```
oid:=res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)
slice:=oid[:]
```

Answer (score 3):

https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID

guess that's you want

first, you can assert InsertedID to primitive.ObjectID, then convert to string or something else

```golang
res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID).String()
res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID).Hex()
```

Comment: Yes with this I could convert it to string first and then to a byte slice. I've marked the other answer as correct, because it's slightly simpler, but this works as well. Thanks!